# The name CreateHostBuilder does not exist in the current context ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am following a .NET 5 tutorial but using vs2022 with .NET 6 and I get this error. I would imagine that it has something to do with how the `startup.cs` is now integrated into the `program.cs` file, so I put the code there.

The `program.cs` file is below. The error happens on this line

```
var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
```

`program.cs`:

```
using DevBlogMVC.Data;
using DevBlogMVC.Models;
using DevBlogMVC.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// postgresql connection
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<BlogUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<BlogUser, IdentityRole>(options =>options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

// create initial user roles
builder.Services.AddScoped<DataService>();

// This is the line with the error
var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

var dataService = host.Services.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataService>();
await dataService.ManageDataAsync();
    
host.Run();


builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: I admit I never messed with dotnet 5 that much and jumped right into 6, but it seems as though the startup/program paradigm combined some things and I could see some things getting removed or scope changing. Perhaps a different walkthrough for dotnet 6 would be better? I think you can comfortably assume this code is not right for 6, my program.cs looks very different

Comment: Seems like you're missing a lot here... namespace, class, and Main(string[] args) method.  (I also skipped .net5, but I believe you can still use the old program.cs/startup.cs format... it's definitely still supported in .net6)

Comment: In my program.cs I define CreateHostBuilder method which returns IHostBuilder...  (I don't use the new "minimal" startup format)  Maybe check here for more details: https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/0e0372c3c1d895c3ce195ba983b1e03d

Comment: will the app work well if you comment `var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

var dataService = host.Services.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataService>();
await dataService.ManageDataAsync();host.Run();` these 4 lines?

Comment: let's see the [migration document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-7.0#change-the-content-root-app-name-and-environment), `CreateHostBuilder` is replaced by `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
`

Comment: Thanks for the info that did help me understand more about what is going on. I went ahead and rebuilt the project in .net5 an it is working. Cheers.